# Is there a more elegant solution for this issue?

Tags: java

I'm working on a piece of code that evaluates a String against a bunch of different regexes.

The regexes are really complicated and were decided by the Product Owner. I basically have to give a better score depending on how close the String is from a perfect match.

I have 3 different regexes right now, one for a perfect match, one for a good match, and other for half match. I might get more levels laters so that is why I'm concerned with the current version of the code.

I tried to simplify the code as much as possible so you can just copy and past it to have a better look in your favorite IDE. You don't need to worry about the implementation of any of those methods. I ommited all of them since they already work as expected.

```
public class MatchEvaluator {

    private static final double PERFECT_MATCH = 1.0;
    private static final double GOOD_MATCH = .9;
    private static final double HALF_MATCH = .5;

    private Integer baseScore = 50;

    public double evaluate(String searchTerm) {

        String suggestion = null;

        double score = 0;

        boolean isPerfectMatch = false;

        Integer searchValue = checkPerfectMatch(searchTerm);

        if (searchValue != null) {

            score = searchValue * baseScore * PERFECT_MATCH;
            suggestion = searchTerm;
            isPerfectMatch = true;
        } else {

            searchValue = checkGoodMatch(searchTerm);

            if (searchValue != null) {

                score = searchValue * baseScore * GOOD_MATCH;
                suggestion = createSuggestion(searchTerm);

            } else {

                searchValue = checkHalfMatch(searchTerm);

                if (searchValue != null) {

                    score = searchValue * baseScore * HALF_MATCH;
                    suggestion = createSuggestion(searchTerm);

                } 
            }
        }

        //Do something with suggestion
        //Do something with searchValue
        //Do something with isPerfectMatch

        return score;

    }

    private Integer checkHalfMatch(String searchTerm) {
        return null;
    }

    private String createSuggestion(String searchTerm) {
        return searchTerm;
    }

    private Integer checkGoodMatch(String searchTerm) {
        return null;
    }

    private Integer checkPerfectMatch(String searchTerm) {
        return null;
    }


}
```

Those nested 'ifs' hurt my eyes every time I look at them, and it will get even worse if I get more levels. So my question is: Is there a better way to do this? Or a more elegant solution?

**EDIT:** Thank you all for the great answers.

Comment: `} else if ((searchValue = ...) != null) {`

Comment: Create an Interface `Matcher` with three subclasses encapsulating your three methods, then put those in a list and iterate that list until one returns a non-null value.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @tobias_k The thing is, that I have different behaviors depending on how good of a match was. For instance, if you look closer, I set isPerfectMatch to true in case it's the perfect match.

Comment: @BrenoQ Well, the behaviour is less different if you assume the other branches setting `isPerfectMatch = false`. See my answer.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you. Would you like to post your comment as an answer? I'll use it for now, since there is no need to create new classes and looks way better than mine. If many other levels come up I will use tobias_k solution. If you don't want to post as an answer I'll just accept his answer.

Comment: @BrenoQ posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is just to assign the variable in the check:

```
Integer searchValue;
if ((searchValue = checkPerfectMatch(searchTerm)) != null) {
  // ...
} else if ((searchValue = checkGoodMatch(searchTerm)) != null) {
  // ...
} else if ((searchValue = checkHalfMatch(searchTerm)) != null) {
  // ...
}
```

All you're really avoiding here is the slow rightward shift in the bodies of the following conditionals. It is not necessarily the most pleasant, as side effects in conditions are easy to miss when you're reading the code.

Mind you, this does look a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an `interface`, `abstract class`, or `enum` for a generic `Matcher`:

```
interface Matcher {
    Integer checkMatch(String searchTerm);
    boolean isPerfectMatch();
    double getMatchScore();
}
```

Implement that interface for your three (or possibly more) matchers, encapsulating those three methods that you already have and also implementing the other two methods. Now you can put those matchers in a list and just iterate the list until you get a non-`null` score.

```
List<Matcher> matchers = Arrays.asList(
        new PerfectScoreMatcher(), 
        new GoodScoreMatcher(), 
        new HalfScoreMatcher());

for (Matcher m : matchers) {
    Integer searchValue = m.checkMatch(searchTerm);
    if (searchValue != null) {
        score = searchValue * baseScore * m.getMatchScore();
        isPerfectMatch = m.isPerfectMatch();
        suggestion = isPerfectMatch ? searchTerm
                                    : createSuggestion(searchTerm);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: An enum might be a good choice.

Comment: I really like your answer. It's scalable too. I will accept your answer if @AndyTurner doesn't post his comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you essentially have a list of regexes, each one associated with a score. You want to return the score as soon as a regex has matched. You could create a mini class to hold each regex and associated score, then make a list of these and keep processing until you match. Something like this:

```
class RegexScore {
  String regex; // I usually make these public in these mini-classes
  double score;
}

List<RegexScore> regexList = your regexes in order
boolean match = false;
Iterator<RegexScore> iterator = regexList.iterator();
while (!match && iterator.hasNext()) {
  RegexScore regex = iterator.next();
  String regex = regexScore.regex;
  // evaluate regex, if match, calc score and set match = true to break
  // out of loop
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your time. I though of this solution but if you repair in the code I have a different behavior when it is a perfect match: isPerfectMatch = true;

So it really matter knowing that it was the perfect one. 

I basically have different behaviors depending on how good the match was.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a special method for finding an evaluation result - you can use return statement to manipulate the flow.

```
class EvaluationResult {
    double score;
    String suggestion;
    boolean isPerfectMatch;

    public EvaluationResult(double score, String suggestion, boolean isPerfectMatch) {
        this.score = score;
        this.suggestion = suggestion;
        this.isPerfectMatch = isPerfectMatch;
    }
}

public EvaluationResult evaluate(String searchTerm) {
    Integer searchValue = checkPerfectMatch(searchTerm);
    if (searchValue != null) {
        return new EvaluationResult(searchValue * baseScore * PERFECT_MATCH, searchTerm, true);
    }

    searchValue = checkGoodMatch(searchTerm);
    if (searchValue != null) {

        return new EvaluationResult(searchValue * baseScore * GOOD_MATCH, createSuggestion(searchTerm), false);
    } 

    searchValue = checkHalfMatch(searchTerm);
    if (searchValue != null) {
        return new EvaluationResult(searchValue * baseScore * HALF_MATCH, createSuggestion(searchTerm), false);
    }

    return null; //null or null value based on your preference
}
```

If you are on java 8+ you can use lambdas and streams. Also you can work on reducing code duplication.

UPD: java 8 version

```
public EvaluationResult evaluate(String searchTerm) {
    return Stream.<Function<String, EvaluationResult>>of(this::checkPerfectMatch, this::checkGoodMatch, this::checkHalfMatch)
            .map(f -> f.apply(searchTerm))
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .findFirst().orElse(null);
}

private EvaluationResult checkPerfectMatch(String searchTerm) {
    Integer searchValue = 1; //doStuff
    return createEvaluationResult(searchValue, PERFECT_MATCH, searchTerm, true);
}

private EvaluationResult checkGoodMatch(String searchTerm) {
    Integer searchValue = 1; //doStuff
    return createEvaluationResult(searchValue, GOOD_MATCH, createSuggestion(searchTerm), true);
}

private EvaluationResult checkHalfMatch(String searchTerm) {
    Integer searchValue = 1; //doStuff
    return createEvaluationResult(searchValue, HALF_MATCH, createSuggestion(searchTerm), true);
}

private EvaluationResult createEvaluationResult(Integer searchValue, double coefficient, String suggestion, boolean isPerfectMatch) {
    return searchValue != null 
            ? new EvaluationResult(searchValue * baseScore * coefficient, suggestion, isPerfectMatch) 
            : null;
}
```